# Lift - Getting the rendered output of a template in a string variable

Tags: scala, lift

We have a web application written in Scala/Liftweb that is working well. Now we need to render some views/reports as PDF files. We already use libraries that will take well-formatted XHTML and output it as PDF so I'm attempting to get the output of a rendered Lift template as a string that I can feed into our PDF library.

How do I get the output of a template as a variable? I have seen [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/26mhElGqUGc) where David Pollak talks about using S.render which returns a NodeSeq, but we're not making much progress on this front.

Ideally I'd do something like:

```
val seq = S.render(NodeSeq, ???)
val stringOutput = seq.toString()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do something like this, it should render the page:

```
val htmlString:Box[String] = for{
  r <- S.request
  t <- Templates("index" :: Nil)
} yield S.render(t, r.request))
```

Where `index` should be replaced by the path of the template you want to render. That should work for basic instances, but you'll need some additional work if you use `Menu.params` or other URL type variables.

**Update:**

If you need to access session objects outside of the HTTP request thread, you will need to initialize the session. To do so, you could modify the above like so:

```
val html = for{
  r <- S.request
  sn <- S.session 
  t <- Templates("index" :: Nil)
} yield S.initIfUninitted(sn) { 
  S.render(t, r.request)) 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should work, but the return type on `htmlString` will be `Box[NodeSeq]` - you'll at least want to do `S.render(t, r.request).toString` in the yield.

Comment: Oops, I still have a problem. I renders the templates, but doesn't see any of my SessionVar objects that the template uses. It almost acts like it runs the template without seeing the User object that is logged in. Any idea how to make the S.render see the current session information so the variables are populated?

Comment: Are you processing in a separate thread from where your session is initialized? If so, there is an `S.initIfUninitted` method you can use. I'll update the answer to show how you can use that

Comment: That didn't help. I wonder if the problem is that I'm doing this inside a RestHelper object. I'll read up on RestHelper to see if there is something special I need to do to see the session from in there.

Comment: Ok, the problem was the call to LiftRules I used for my RestHelper. I was using LiftRules.statelessDispatchTable(MyRestHelperObject) - *duh* - instead of LiftRules.dispatch(MyRestHelperObject). All good now!